# How can I return an object using std::min with std::less

Tags: c++, templates, min

I have the following code where I need to return the object having a specific smallest element. I need to use std::greater and std::less.  The code is working but this is not what I want. I want to have `x3` to have both `x` and `y` of the structures having the smallest `x`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct X {
    
int x;
int y ;
};

class A {
    public:
    A(){}
    template<typename T>
    static X getValue(const X&x1,const X&x2) {
        X x3;
        x3.x =  std::min(x1.x, x2.x,T());
        return x3;
       // x3 = std::min(x1.x, x2.x,T()); Wont work for sure.
    }

};

int main()
{
    X x1;
    x1.x = 10;
    X x2;
    x2.x = 20;
    
    cout<<A::getValue<std::less<int>>(x1,x2).x << std::endl;
    cout<<A::getValue<std::less<int>>(x1,x2).y << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have to use `std::min`? Seems like an `if` would be sufficient.

Comment: I need to use template. how can if work with the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the function like this:

```
template<typename T>
static X getValue(const X&x1,const X&x2) {
    return T{}(x1.x, x2.x) ? x1 : x2;
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PBjDpF).

Alternatively, you could pass the comparison object as an argument:

```
template<typename T>
static X getValue(const X&x1,const X&x2, T comp) {
   return comp(x1.x, x2.x) ? x1 : x2;
}
```

and call it like this:

```
cout << A::getValue(x1, x2, std::less{}).x << std::endl;
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zFSgfA).

Answer (score 2):

It's probably best if you define relational operators for `X`

```
#include <tuple>

struct X {
    int x;
    int y ;
};

bool operator<(X lhs, X rhs) { return std::tie(lhs.x, lhs.y) < std::tie(rhs.x, rhs.y); }
bool operator>(X lhs, X rhs) { ... }
bool operator<=(X lhs, X rhs) { ... }
bool operator>=(X lhs, X rhs) { ... }
```

then you can do

```
template<class Pred>
X get_value(X x1, X x2) { return std::min(x1, x2, Pred()); }
```

and you should probably use `std::less<>` and `std::greater<>` instead of `std::less<int>` and `std::greater<int>` as the template for `void` is specialized to do the correct thing.

**EDIT:**
If you don't care about relational operators for `X` then @cigien's answer is probably fine